# How to open phone camera in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using 'react-webcam' component in my application. For web it is working for me but in mobile device it is not working. And My client needs that he immediately get to the phone's camera if he click take camera button in mobile device. please anyone help me to fix this issue

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're after, but you should be able to access the phone's camera using this api https://whatwebcando.today/camera-microphone.html.  Not sure if there is a react library that wraps this up for you though.

Answer (score 3):

There is an rpm package which can be used to open the camera. I have not used this yet.

Just try yourself.

[npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5-camera-photo)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here,](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5-camera-photo#required-working-environment-for-getusermedia) Your service should be served secure, either from localhost or an https connection.

AND in ios>=11 Apple restricts WebRTC to Safari only!